# Is there any feature is providing the microsoft teams to load static web pages(html/aspx) in browser

Tags: asp.net, windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-teams

[image] 
I am trying to upload the html file and aspx file in teams. once it is loaded then get the copy of files address
 and i am going to load that copied path url in browser but it is not showing web content which i design like web page.
 in browser (html/aspx) files are downloading. If i am trying to load apsx file in browser it was showing like error(Something went wrong File Not Found),
so  want i like is that is there any feature to load in browser?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do ? I could not understand the question. What do you mean by "uploading html file in teams".

Comment: from the above image,uploaded different formats of files in teams, Now i want to copy the link from copy link option of any file it should be open in browser. i want to host static html page in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your detailed explanation.

First of all, Teams does not host any html or aspx file itself. So you can not upload a file and use the *URL* to render web page in browser. The file *URL* is a link to that uploaded file location. That's the reason the file is getting downloaded in browser.

Secondly, it is other way round. You can run your website in any other server and use that URL to configure a tab in MS Teams.

Please go through these links

[What can Teams apps do?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview#what-can-teams-apps-do)

[How do tabs work?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs#how-do-tabs-work)